# Test Exception with Rspec Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec

I wanna do a test on a method call similar to:

```
call_to_method_1 param1
```

this method can raise for example:

```
raise msg1 if ...
raise msg2 if ...
```

My question is How to test exception with its msg1, msg2 exception messages wtih RSpec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
describe SomeClass do
  let(:some_object) { described_class.new }

  it 'should raise an exception' do
    some_object.some_method('param').should raise_error(ExceptionClass, "exception_message")
  end
end
```

if you `raise "message"` then the `ExceptionClass` will be instance of `RuntimeClass`.

IMO it's better to raise specific type of exception instead of relying on message though.

Comment: thanks you. It works passing  raising message to the last arg of raise_error. however I have edited your answer to match exactly what was asked.